# Show that $X$ is a submartingale, given some assumptions. Is the following solution correct?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales, filtrations

> Let $X=(X_n)_{n>0}$ be an increasing sequence of integrable r.v.'s, each $X_n$ being $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable. Show that $X$ is a submartingale.

**MY SOLUTION**

What I have to show is that, *given that*:

$1)$ $X_n(\omega) < X_{n+1}(\omega)$, each $n$ (or, equivalently, $X_m(\omega)\leq X_n(\omega)$, each $m\leq n$);

$2)$ $\mathbb{E}(|X_n|)< \infty$, each $n$;

$3)$ $X_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable, each $n$;

*then* $X$ is a submartingale, that is:

$1.1)$ $\mathbb{E}(|X_n|)< \infty$, each $n$;

$1.2)$ $X_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable, each $n$;

$1.3)$ $\mathbb{E}(X_n|\mathcal{F}_m) \geq X_m$ a.s., each $m\leq n$.

Clearly, $1.1)$ corresponds to $2)$ and $1.2)$ corresponds to $3)$. Hence, one is left with proving $1.3)$.

To this, one can state that, given assumption $1)$, for each $m\leq n$:
\begin{equation}        
X_n(\omega)\geq X_m(\omega)
\end{equation}
Then, taking expectation on both sides and conditioning with respect to $\mathcal{F}_m$, taking into account assumption $3)$, one has that:
\begin{equation}        
\mathbb{E}(X_n(\omega)|\mathcal{F}_m) \geq \mathbb{E}(X_m(\omega)|\mathcal{F}_m) = X_m 
\end{equation}
which is exactly point $1.3)$.

*Is the above reasoning correct?*

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: You have $X_n(\omega) \geq X_m(\omega)$ at each $\omega$. How does that tell you that $E[X_n | \mathcal F_m ](\omega)\geq E[X_m | \mathcal F_m](\omega)$? You need to explain this. (Essentially, why is the conditional expectation of a non-negative random variable non-negative?)

Comment: Do you mean that I am not allowed, starting from $X_n(\omega) \geq X_m(\omega)$, to take expectation on both sides and to condition with respect to $\mathcal{F}_m$ finally getting $\mathbb{E}(X_n(\omega)|\mathcal{F}_m) \geq \mathbb{E}(X_m(\omega)|\mathcal{F}_m) = X_m$? 

Or do you mean that my reasoning is correct BUT I have to clarify why the conditional expectation of a non-negative random variable is non-negative as well?

Comment: When applying expectation and conditioning with respect to $F_m$ on both sides, I have simply applied monotonicity property of conditional expectation, according to which: if $X_n(\omega)\geq X_m(\omega)$ a.s., then $\mathbb{E}(X_n|\mathcal{F}_m) \geq \mathbb{E}(X_m|\mathcal{F}_m)=X_m$. Hence, why do you stress the importance of explaining why the conditional expectation of a non-negative random variable is non-negative? I have just used monotonicity property of conditional expectation and the random variables are not necessarily non-negative (this is not specified) @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: Sure, @user600927, I am convinced. The thing is, for me it was always an exercise to prove the monotonicity of the conditional expectation. However, you are assuming it, so I thought you were doing so perhaps without realizing it could be non-trivial. I do not see any gaps in your proof. I do think in such a circumstance that you can answer your own question, although you cannot award the bounty to yourself, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, I gave it for granted. How could I prove monotonicity in an explicit manner? @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: Well, the random variable $X_n-X_m$ is non-negative for $m \leq n$ by assumption.Let $Y$ denote the event : $\{E[X_n-X_m | \mathcal F_m] < 0\}$. We would like to show $Y$ has measure zero. But $Y \in \mathcal F_m$! (Because it is part of the sigma algebra generated by some $\mathcal F_m$ measurable random variable). Finally, by definition, $E[(X_n-X_m)1_{Y}]  = E[E[(X_n-X_m)|\mathcal F_m]1_Y]$. Continued...

Comment: The LHS is clearly non-negative, because $X_n-X_m$ is *non-negative*. However, the right hand side will be *negative* if $Y$ has non-zero measure (for any random variable, $Z$, $E[Z1_{Z < 0}]$ will be non-positive, and negative if $Z<0$ has positive measure). It follows that the RHS and LHS are $0$ i.e. $Y$ must be of measure zero. This implies $E[X_n|\mathcal F_m] \geq E[X_m | \mathcal F_m]$ almost surely. Finally, this proof is as good as the proof of "conditional expectation preserves monotonicity".

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time and help, now I got it @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: @user600927 Thank you very much.I want to write an answer. What would you suggest I write, of what I have to offer you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only to answer the question from the comments:

- Integrability and Adaptedness are already part of the assumptions;
- We need to show that $\mathbb E[X_n | \mathcal F_m] \geq X_m$ for each $n \geq m$. By adaptedness and linearity, it is enough to show that $E[X_n-X_m | \mathcal F_m]$ is a non-negative random variable;
- But this is clear : let $Y$ be the event $\{E[X_n-X_m | \mathcal F_m] < 0\}$. Since $E[X_n-X_m| \mathcal F_m]$ is a $\mathcal F_m$ measurable random variable, the event $Y$ belongs in $\mathcal F_m$ i.e. $1_Y$ (the indicator function of $Y$) belongs to $\mathcal F_m$;
- By definition of conditional expectation, $E[(X_n-X_m)1_Y] = E[E[X_n-X_m | \mathcal F_m] 1_Y]$. The LHS of this is non-negative since $X_n \geq X_m$ everywhere, and therefore on $Y$. Therefore, the RHS is non-negative. However, $1_YE[X_n-X_m | \mathcal F_m]$ is a *non-positive* random variable! So the integral can be non-negative precisely when $1_Y$ is $0$ almost surely i.e. $Y$ has measure zero. This is the same as $E[X_n | \mathcal F_m] \geq X_m$ almost surely.

Finally, all conditions are complete and we have that $X_m$ is an $\mathcal F_m$-submartingale.

---

Note that we have proved above a more general statement :

> Let $X,Y$ be random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ and let $\mathcal G \subset \mathcal F$ be any $\sigma$-algebra. Then, if $X \geq Y$ we have $E[X | \mathcal G] \geq E[Y | \mathcal G]$.

In words, if one random variable dominates another, then even if I provide you with any information, the domination will continue to hold. This is obvious when you think of it.